# Could we create Virtual host for modules in Zend framework1.11 and Wamp server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, virtualhost

First of all thanks for read my question:

I have created a module in Zend framework1.11

**Module name** = Client

Now as per our requirement we need to create virtual host on wamp server.

a) http://client.com

Following is the settings, which i have done in the **C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin client.com
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/loyality/application/modules/client/"
ServerName client.com
ServerAlias www.client.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

After that enable the window host file under **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc/hosts**

But i am getting error **500 Internal Server Error**

In the error log i have found following error:

```
[Fri Jan 02 12:47:12.154296 2015] [core:error] [pid 4324:tid 1600] [client 127.0.0.1:50923] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Please suggest, how can i made **Virtual host** for **modules** in zend framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can resolve this issue with following settings:

Here i am using Wamp server, Zend framework.

**Step 1:** First we need to enable `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` line in the apache file **httpd.conf**

For example:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**Step 2:** We need to define Virtual host in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file which is present in the bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

For example: We can define virtual host like following code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/loyality/public/"
ServerName pizzahut.com 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/loyality/public/"
ServerName dominos.com 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/loyality/public/"
ServerName client.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

Step3: Now we need to make mappings of IP address to different host names
For example :

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      pizzahut.com
127.0.0.1      www.pizzahut.com

127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      dominos.com
127.0.0.1      www.dominos.com

127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1      client.com
127.0.0.1      www.client.com
```

Step 4: Define or Add constant for default module in the index.php file which is present in the public folder.

For example:

```
defined('DEFAULT_MODULE') || define('DEFAULT_MODULE', "dominos");
```

Step 5: Enable Default module in the application.ini file using following code.

```
resources.frontController.prefixDefaultModule = true
resources.frontController.defaultModule = DEFAULT_MODULE
```

With these above steps, i found solution for this question.

Now Our default module is dominos and when i am running http://www.dominos.com then my dominos module pointing.

Thanks,
Sunny Patial.

Comment: in this case Document root will be DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/loyality/application/modules/client/" for a zend module??